# How to get Makefile to only produce a file name without extension?

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile that exports a markdown file to a pdf file  that uses the same filename as the original markdown file. I used "basename" command but it produces "inputfile.md.pdf" instead of "inputfile.pdf".

Please see my code below (I adapted a code I found on the Internet. Thank you!):

```
.PHONY: pdf docx apa format

FILES := $(wildcard ./*.md)

pdf:
        for file in $(FILES); do \
            pandoc $$file \
            --bibliography mypath \
            --csl mypath \
            --filter pandoc-citeproc \
            --template eisvogel \
            -o $(basename $$file).pdf; \
            open $(basename $$file).pdf; \
        done
```

Anyone who can help me? I'm a novice in Makefile (and programming in general) so any detailed help would be very much appreciated.

I also tried these codes below, but they generated an error message:

`-o $(basename -s ".md" $$file).pdf; \`

`-o $(basename -s .md $$file).pdf; \`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you write `$(basename …)` you get the [`basename` make function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-basename).  This would normally the right thing, but you try to reference a shell variable `file` in its argument, which is unavailable at the make layer.

In this case, it is probably easiest to call the `basename` shell utility, at the shell level.  Therefore, you need to escape the `$` to get shell substitution, like this:

```
        -o "$$(basename -s .md $$file)".pdf; \
        open "$$(basename -s .md $$file)".pdf; \
```

Alternatively, you could try to move the loop to the make layer, perhaps using [`foreach`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html).

Comment: Wonderful! This worked! Thank you very much :) I struggled for this for several hours yesterday.

Comment: I think this also has the advantage of working with filenames with spaces in it whereas the Makefile builtin does not.